# Nodejs lambda function api call returns false

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, aws-lambda, salesforce

I have the following code running on my AWS lamda console. Code finishes fine but doesn't make the api call. Do you know what's wrong in this code or how can track logs?

```
   var http = require('https');

   exports.handler = function (event, context) {

   const _requestData = JSON.stringify('{"Name":"AWS Lambda"}');

   console.log(event +' ____event ' +_requestData + ' ______requestData');

   const _options = {
             host: "login.salesforce.com",
             path: "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Case/",
              method: 'POST',
              port: 80,
              headers: {
                'grant_type' : 'authorization_code', 
                'client_id':'xxxxxx',
                'client_secret':'xxxxxxx',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(_requestData))
              }

  };

  var post_req = http.request(_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('Response Chunk: ' + chunk);
      });
   });
   console.log('post_req' + JSON.stringify(post_req));
   var post_response = post_req.write(_requestData);
   console.log('post_response '+post_response);
   post_req.end();
   context.succeed("done");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are a beginner in Node, Nevermind, you made few mistakes. 
This line  `var post_response = post_req.write(_requestData)` won't give you end result rather it returns `true` if write is a success.You can change function something as like this:

```
var http = require('https');
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    const _requestData = JSON.stringify('{"Name":"AWS Lambda"}');

    console.log(event + ' ____event ' + _requestData + ' ______requestData');

    const _options = {
        host: "login.salesforce.com",
        path: "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Case/",
        method: 'POST',
        port: 80,
        headers: {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'client_id': 'xxxxxx',
            'client_secret': 'xxxxxxx',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(_requestData))
        }

    };

    var post_req = http.request(_options, function(res) {
        let post_response;
        let chunks = []
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('Response Chunk: ' + chunk);
            chunks.push(chunk)
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            post_response = JSON.parse(Buffer.concate(chunks).toString())
            // once request done send lambda response
            context.succeed("done");
        })
    });
    post_req.end();
    pos_req.on('error', function(err) {
        context.succeed("failed");
    })

}
```

If you are Node beginner I would recommend learning async programming, stream, callbacks, promises and of course async-await.